# Async alternative

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-ctp, onedrive

I am trying to implement this code in my app to backup data to skydrive http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2012/07/11/skydrive-backup-of-your-mobile-applets-get-some-common-ground/

but how I can not install Async CTP (I tested during 2 - 3 days but async ctp is not installed fine...already I have tried solutions but the problems persist). Would be possible to do the same but not using async? how to wait to complete the task to continue?

using these tools "Windows Phone SDK 7.1 and 7.1.1 Update": https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

(...)

```
var rootFolders = JObject.Parse((await client.GetAsyncTask("/me/skydrive/files?filter=folders,albums")).RawResult);
var progDataFolder = rootFolders["data"].FirstOrDefault(f => f.Value<string>("name").Equals("programdata", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
string progDataFolderId;
if (progDataFolder == null)
{
    var result = await client.PostAsyncTask("me/skydrive/",
        new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "name", "ProgramData" } });**

    progDataFolderId = JObject.Parse(result.RawResult).Value<string>("folder_id");
}
else
{
    progDataFolderId = progDataFolder.Value<string>("id");
}

var windowsPhoneFolder = JObject.Parse((await client.GetAsyncTask(string.Concat("/", progDataFolderId, "/files?filter=folders,albums"))).RawResult)["data"]
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Value<string>("name").Equals("windows phone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
string windowsPhoneFolderId;
if (windowsPhoneFolder == null)
{
    var result = await client.PostAsyncTask(string.Concat("/", progDataFolderId),
        new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "name", "Windows Phone" } });**

    windowsPhoneFolderId = JObject.Parse(result.RawResult).Value<string>("id");
}
else
{
    windowsPhoneFolderId = windowsPhoneFolder.Value<string>("id");
}
```

(...)

Alternative to do this. example:

```
var result = await client.PostAsyncTask("me/skydrive/",
            new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "name", "ProgramData" } });
```

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I'm pretty sure the Async Targeting Pack will *not* work for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: @StephenCleary - This is not true. I have an application that uses it. It is just tricky to install the Async CTP with VS 2010 under some circumstances.

Comment: @ananthonline: I was talking about the Async Targeting Pack (VS2012), not the Async CTP (VS2010).

Comment: Ah, my bad :) I haven't gotten down and dirty with VS 2012 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Task`s, you can use what's called "continuation passing style". Essentially, everywhere you would use `await`, you instead call `Task.ContinueWith` and pass in the rest of your method. Loops are more complex, but can also be handled with continuations.

Note that `GetAsyncTask` may not work correctly if you don't have the Async CTP installed correctly. So in your case, I recommend you use the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) already supported by the `LiveConnectClient` class: e.g., subscribe to the `GetCompleted` event and then call `GetAsync`. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shelly_guos_ms_blog/archive/2011/09/20/get-started-on-live-sdk-for-windows-phone.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the same code doesn't use any methods that are only available in a new version of the framework, you can simply use TPL methods to reproduce what `await` does.  `await` runs continuations with the synchronization context of the code that executed the await.  So, to duplicate that you need to use an overload of ContinueWith that accepts a TaskScheduler and pass in the TaskScheduler from the current context.  For example:

```
TaskScheduler taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
client.PostAsyncTask("me/skydrive/", new Dictionary<string, object>() {{"name", "ProgramData"}})
    .ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                    progDataFolderId= JObject.Parse(result.RawResult).Value<string>("folder_id");
                    });
```

Now, that's the simple part of getting one `await` translated to a TPL method with a task scheduler.  What the compiler is actually doing is creating a state machine in your `async` method (the method with all the `await` code).  That state machine has broken up your original code into chunks and keeping track of various things like `progDataFolder == null` because, in your case, the code after the first else can be invoked in two different ways.  One is asynchronous--if `progDataFolder` is null then the code after the else is invoked asynchronously, if `progDataFolder` is not null the the `progDataFolderId` is set from the `progDataFolder` instance and the code after the else is involved *synchronously*.  So, you'll have to mode that properly with TPL methods.  i.e. you won't run the code after the else in a continuation when `progDataFolder` is not `null`.